# Is there a word for this?

Tags: single-word-requests, british-english

Is there a word for a lack of order and control by authority?
I think I have forgotten the word for it and can't seem to find any help anywhere.

Comment: The question asks for a word to describe the 'lack of order and control' by authority. So there is an authority but it lacks power.

Answer (score 4):

That sounds like *anarchy*.

> **anarchy** *noun*
>   A state of disorder due to absence or nonrecognition of authority.
>   ‘he must ensure public order in a country threatened with anarchy’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/anarchy)

Answer (score 0):

**bedlam**  [Oxford](http://www.oed.com/viewdictionaryentry/Entry/16879)

> b. abstr. **Madness, lunacy**. Also as interjection. 1598   J. Marston
>   Certaine Satyres in Metamorph. Pigmalions Image 53   Bedlame, Frenzie,
>   Madnes, Lunacie, I challenge all your moody Empery. 1640   W.
>   Habington Queene of Arragon sig. I3   Bedlam this is pretty sport.
>
> 4. fig. **A scene of mad confusion or uproar**. 1661   A. Cowley Vision Cromwell 6   Thou doest..A Babel, and a Bedlam grow. 1713   R. Steele
>      in Guardian 12 Aug. 1/2   Our House is a sort of Bedlam, and nothing
>      in Order. 1850   T. Carlyle Latter-day Pamphlets viii. 39   That all
>      this was a Donnybrook Bedlam,..proceeding nowhither.

fascinating etymology: (same citation)

> Etymology: Middle English Bedlem = Bethlem, Bethlehem; applied to the
>   Hospital of St. Mary of Bethlehem, in London, founded as a priory in
>   1247, with the special duty of receiving and entertaining the bishop
>   of St. Mary of Bethlehem, and the canons, etc. of this, the mother
>   church, as often as they might come to England. In 1330 it is
>   mentioned as ‘an hospital,’ and in 1402 as a hospital for lunatics
>   (Timbs); in 1346 it was received under the protection of the city of
>   London, and on the Dissolution of the Monasteries, it was granted to
>   the mayor and citizens, and in 1547 incorporated as a royal foundation
>   for the reception of lunatics. Thence the modern sense, of which
>   instances appear early in 16th cent.

Comment: "Bedlam" in synonymous with "chaos" and doesn't refer specifically to a lack of authority or rule. E.g. "It was bedlam in the streets even after the government declared martial law; the people's grief and fury were too great to be restrained." There is authority present, but they're overwhelmed. OP seems to be looking, instead, for a term where there may or may not be violent upheaval, but there is no common law or authority to enforce a prescribed order on a people/peoples: anarchy.